# Is it necessary to have a macro ring flash to take macro photos?

Tags: flash, macro

I just got a macro lens but it turns out the subject is not bright enough. I am wondering if  I need to buy a macro flash for macro photography?

The flash seems expensive and I am wondering if it is an absolute requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am just wondering do I need to buy a macro flash for macro photography?

It's not necessary unless you want exactly the effect that a ring flash (or similar) gives.

If you just want better illumination, you could for example buy [or build](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/07/how-to-diy-10-macro-photo-studio.html) a macro soft box. Alternately, you could buy something like the [Orbis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0033WT9TK), which is a ring-shaped reflector that kinda-sorta makes your speedlight work like a ring flash.

In fact, you have an advantage with macro photography in that the subject is relatively small, so you don't need a *lot* of light so much as you need light *in the right place*. So, you could build your own lighting setup with lots of small lights -- even a string of white Christmas tree lights could work. Or buy a [5-meter strip of white LEDs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GL5R56) and arrange them to light your subject.

Comment: Ah ha, I used to take landscape photo and I doesn't know so much about macro photo. Seems like I need more gear to take a good macro photo. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly a flash (or continuous artificial lighting) is not absolutely necessary but makes things a lot easier, especially if you are stopping the lens right down to maximise your depth of field.

A ring flash is usually recommended for macro photography purely because a regular hotshoe mounted flash will be obscured by the lens when you are close to your subject. these flashes are expensive, however there's a much cheaper solution, just get the light off the hotshoe.

You don't need much power for macro, so just about any camera flash will do if you use it off camera. The easiest way is to get an off-shoe cord. A batter solution is wireless triggers. If you want a really low cost option than an angle poise lamp very close to the subject will work.